# GitHub OAuth no scopes being returned in access token

Tags: php, oauth, github-api

I am working on implementing OAuth with GitHub, but even though in the request I specify a scope I don't get any scopes back in the response which means I haven't got access to a private repository and keep getting a 404 (from GitHubs documentation they return a 404 if oauth is not set up correctly to avoid giving away information about a private repo).

I first of all send a request to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=redacted&state=redacted&scope=repo&redirect_uri=http://localhost/`

This works and I get directed to the login for GitHub and get a code back and then send a request to `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` and use the following post parameters

```
"client_id" => "redacted,
"client_secret" => "redacted",
"code" => "redacted,
"scope" => "repo",
"redirect_uri" => "http://localhost
```

This works and I get an access token and can get the users details but the scope is blank. I get the following JSON object response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [access_token] => redacted
    [token_type] => bearer
    [scope] => 
)
```

I've been following the steps from `https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps`

How do I make it so my access code has the scopes I've requested as I am adding scope=repo to the oauth request so don't understand why I don't get it back.

Comment: Have you also read this page? https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

Comment: Yea I did, but it basically says what I've already said I've done in the question unless I'm missing something. I've added a scope to the get parameter in authorize endpoint - although that page says it shows the scopes but I can't see it show anything on the login screen

Comment: I've realised what I've done. I created a GitHub app instead of an oauth app. Changed it and appears to work correctly now